# Argument of type "str" cannot be assigned to parameter "__key" of type "slice" in function "__setitem__" "str" is incompatible with "slice"

Tags: python, python-3.x

My code is running with no errors but VS Code warns me with a warning message after I added the `_update_scale` method in this class:

```
class AlienAnimation:
    """This class manages the animation of an alien,
    based on its level prefix. The alien frames are chosen
    based on the current level in the game.
    """

    frames = {}

    def __init__(self, game, alien, scale=1.0):
        self.alien = alien
        self.game = game
        self.scale = scale

        self.frame_update_rate = 6
        self.frame_counter = 0
        self.current_frame = 0

        level_prefix = LEVEL_PREFIX.get(game.stats.level // 4 + 1, "Alien7")
        if level_prefix not in AlienAnimation.frames:
            AlienAnimation.frames[level_prefix] = load_alien_images(level_prefix) #  this returns a list

        self.frames = AlienAnimation.frames[level_prefix]
        self.image = self.frames[self.current_frame]

    def _update_scale(self):
        scaled_width = int(self.image.get_width() * self.scale)
        scaled_height = int(self.image.get_height() * self.scale)
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (scaled_width, scaled_height))
        self.frames = [pygame.transform.scale(frame, (scaled_width, scaled_height)) for frame in self.frames]  # If I remove this line, the warnings are gone.
```

Warning messages:

```
Argument of type "str" cannot be assigned to parameter "__key" of type "slice" in function "__setitem__"
  "str" is incompatible with "slice"

Argument of type "str" cannot be assigned to parameter "__s" of type "slice" in function "__getitem__"
  "str" is incompatible with "slice"
```

The warnings are pointing me to:
`AlienAnimation.frames[level_prefix] = load_alien_images(level_prefix)`
and
`self.frames = AlienAnimation.frames[level_prefix]`

What does this warning mean? Is there a way to not receive it?

Comment: What does `load_alien_images(level_prefix)` return?

Comment: A list of frames, loaded with `pygame.image.load`.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be mixing up `dict` and `list` for the `frames` attribute:

```py
# Initializes a dict
frames = {}

# Updates the dict
AlienAnimation.frames[level_prefix] = load_alien_images(level_prefix) # Update dict

# Replaces the dict by what is in frames[level_prefix], you say it will become a list
self.frames = AlienAnimation.frames[level_prefix] 

# Sets a list
self.frames = [pygame.transform.scale(frame, (scaled_width, scaled_height)) for frame in self.frames]
```

A slice is a part of a list: `frames[0]` returns the first item in the list. This must be an integer, and can not be a string.

Comment: `# Replaces the dict by what is in frames[level_prefix], ...`: But that's not a _replacement_, it adds an instance attribute, the class attribute is still there?